# Using rita.js to generate alliteration

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm currently experimenting with Daniel Shiffman's [tutorial on rita.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIPEvh8HbGQ). Right now, I'm trying to change the code to generate alliteration (i.e. words that start with the same letter) rather than a totally random word. I keep getting back errors that say  "alliteration is not a function." How can I get the code to work?

Here's the current code I'm working with:

```
var input;
var button;
var lexicon;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  lexicon = new RiLexicon();

  input = createInput('It was a dark and stormy night.');
  button = createButton('submit');
  input.changed(processRita);
  button.mousePressed(processRita);
  input.size(200);
}

function processRita() {
var s = input.value();
var rs = new RiString(s);
var words = rs.words();
var pos = rs.pos();
console.log(words);
console.log(pos);

var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 
   if (/nn.*/.test(pos[i])) {
      output += lexicon.alliteration(pos[i]);
      console.log(nn);
    } else {
      output += words[i];
    }

    output += " ";
  }
  createP(output);
}
```

Comment: A quick look at the reference [here](https://rednoise.org/rita/reference/index.php) shows that RiLexicon has a method alliteration**s** rather than alliteration, so might just need to change the method name.

Comment: I've tried both, as well as the "isAlliteration" tag, and none of it works.

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of syntactical issues:

- Change lexicon.alliteration to lexicon.alliteration**s**
- The line `console.log(nn)` errors because **nn** is a variable that does not exist, so remove this line.

---

The alliterations method is being called with pos[i] as parameter, at a time when pos[i] has a value of "nn", which is a 'part-of-speech' tag returned by the pos method. It fails to return any alliterations because the alliterations method actually expects a word rather than a part-of-speech tag.
So you should pass it words[i] instead of pos[i]

However it returns an array so you will end up with lots of words thus:

`It was a dark and stormy abnormal,abnormally,abomination,acknowledge,acknowledged,acknowledgement ...`

So instead if you want a random alliteration you could change it to:

```
var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
```

So the full code becomes:

```
var input;
var button;
var lexicon;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  lexicon = new RiLexicon();

  input = createInput('It was a dark and stormy night.');
  button = createButton('submit');
  input.changed(processRita);
  button.mousePressed(processRita);
  input.size(200);
}

function processRita() {
var s = input.value();
var rs = new RiString(s);
var words = rs.words();
var pos = rs.pos();
console.log(words);
console.log(pos);

var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 
   if (/nn.*/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
    } else {
      output += words[i];
    }

    output += " ";
  }
  createP(output);
}
```

---

Unfortunately RiTa's definition of alliteration (where the first stressed consonant of the words match) is not what you are after.

Assuming that you are not simply after words that start with the same letter but words that start with the same phoneme, I can't find
an efficient way of doing it using RiTa's API, though I have written the following function which seems to do the job; but it follows bad practice because it accesses some of RiTa's 'private' members that are not intended to be accessed. For reference I am using RiTa 1.1.40.

```
function firstPhoneAlliteration(searchWord) {

    var phoneSplitRegex = new RegExp(' |-|' + RiTa.STRESSED); //space or hyphen or the stress character

    function getFirstPhone(word) {
        return lexicon._getRawPhones(word).split(phoneSplitRegex)[0];
    }

    var firstPhoneOfSearchWord = getFirstPhone(searchWord);

    var wordsInLexicon = lexicon.keys;
    var matchedWords = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < wordsInLexicon.length; i++) {
        if (firstPhoneOfSearchWord === getFirstPhone(wordsInLexicon[i])) {
            matchedWords.push(wordsInLexicon[i]);
        }
    }

    return matchedWords;

}
```

You probably only want words with a matching part-of-speech tag (so that 'night' for example will be replaced with a noun), so you
could filter the words as follows:

```
var alliterations = firstPhoneAlliteration(words[i])
    .filter(function (word) {
        return (RiTa.getPosTags(word)[0] === pos[i]);
    });
```

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for your help! However, this code doesn't seem to produce alliterations, just random nouns. Any ideas?

Comment: @WiriginiaVoolf I've added some info about generating words starting with the same phoneme.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. The updated code is not working for me, maybe for a number of reasons. For now, I've decided to abandon this idea and move on to something else.